# Embedding PowerPoint Chart into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

If I embed a PowerPoint Presentation within an Excel Worksheet, then, within the PowerPoint, set up chart objects on each slide, can I go into the data table for the chart object, and have it refer back to the Excel spreadsheet for its data?

If so, how?

Note: I'm asking for Office 2003

Comment: You could just try it and see what happens.

Comment: Here is a link to another Stack Overflow question that seems to answer yours.
Hope this helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207267/how-to-update-excel-embedded-charts-in-powerpoint

Comment: use www.pptxbuilder.com

Answer (score 0):

On the **Insert** menu, point to **Picture**, and then click **Chart**.

Graph will immediately embed a chart into the document that depicts the data contained in the PowerPoint's chart table. Graph will also display a datasheet containing the chart data. The datasheet contains a copy of the data from the original PowerPoint table that you selected. If you want to change the values plotted on the chart, you must edit the numbers within the datasheet.

Note: Make sure that you have installed Microsoft Graph.