# Generate PowerPoint presentations with Excel sheets / charts embedded in it programatically

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

So what my client wants to accomplish seems pretty simple. We will have PPTX file template with a few Excel sheets embedded in it, and a few charts too.

We have created such template file. We are able to extract it, update excel files that sit in ppt/embedded directory with new ones, and pack it back.

The problem is, the display values of the tables or charts do not update automatically when such file is opened. You have to double click on a spreadsheet table or chart to trigger "edit mode". When you leave it the charts are updated.

We figured that internally, PowerPoint is doing *screenshots* of tables or charts, and uses it to display presentation. This is probably to allow presentation players that do not come with Excel to correctly render the presentation with embedded sheets.

Is there a way I can programatically update the screenshots of tables/charts? Is there some sort of API from Microsoft that would allow me to do that, like "MS Office API".

Maybe there is some way to have MS office configured/scripted, so I send it a file, it runs a VB script on it and returns updated value? I figured I can actually trigger update to screenshots with VB script. But I don't know if I can orchestrate Office program to do what I want.

Help? :)

Comment: This looks like what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14951389/6340326

Comment: Here is the MS documentation on [Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) & [PowerPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745704.aspx) APIs.

Comment: Look for an Application.Update method or an Update method on the OLEObject ... invoke that before quitting the OLE provider application should do the update.