# Updating Powerpoint Charts linked to Password Protected Excel File

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I ve got a password protected excel workbook and a powerpoint presentation which has many charts linked to this workbook. What I am trying to do is updating all charts in the presentation without entring a password. I tried to reach data via *ChartData* object but couldn't find out how to access workbook with a password written in the code. I had also tried creating an excel object  however this time after setting workbook as unprotected I couldn't define the code that refresh links between charts and data.

I appreciate any effort that helps me to solve this problem.

I had found this code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313970/update-powerpoint-chart-using-vba) and I inserted `myChart.ChartData.Workbook.UnProtect Password:="1234", writeResPassword:="1234", ReadOnly:=False, Updatelinks:=3`. Unfortunately it is still asking for password.

```
Sub update2()

Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim myChart As PowerPoint.Chart
Dim Wb As Object
Dim App As Object

Set myPresentation = ActivePresentation

For Each sld In myPresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            Set myChart = shp.Chart
            myChart.ChartData.Activate
            myChart.Refresh
            Set Wb = myChart.ChartData.Workbook
            Set App = Wb.Application
            Wb.Close (0)
        End If
    Next
Next
App.Quit
End Sub
```

I think as it gets to the line `myChart.ChartData.Activate` then password input box is triggered and from that point the rest of the code doesnt work.

I assume that when we reach chart data through powerpoint it runs an explicit app. If so how I can pass the password dialog in that app.

Comment: Please post the code you've got so far