# Refresh Embedded Excel Data in Powerpoint Charts

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to automate the creation of a PowerPoint deck that I create a few times a week. I use a program called Alteryx to update the embedded excel files for all my charts in PowerPoint and that part works great. The problem that I have is that once I open PowerPoint, all the charts look the same as they originally were. It's only when I click edit data, that PowerPoint seems to read the excel changes and updates the chart. I have over 50 charts that I need to update, and clicking edit data on each one is very time consuming.

Is there a macro that can be created that will refresh all charts in my deck?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Update 1

I have tried using the following code from another post, but it results in 50 open workbooks.

```
Dim pptChart As Chart
Dim pptChartData As ChartData
Dim pptWorkbook As Object
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            Set pptChart = shp.Chart
            Set pptChartData = pptChart.ChartData
            pptChartData.Activate
            shp.Chart.REFRESH

            On Error Resume Next
            On Error GoTo 0

        End If
    Next
Next

Set pptWorkbook = Nothing
Set pptChartData = Nothing
Set pptChart = Nothing
```

I tried using the following code to open and close all the embedded workbooks, but it results in an error at this part "ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide s.Slideindex"

```
Sub refreshchart()
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application, sld As Slide
    Dim s As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim gChart As Chart, i As Integer
    ppApp.Visible = True
    i = 3
     Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
    sld.Select

For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
    If s.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
      s.Select                               'select the object
        s.OLEFormat.Activate                 'Activate it (like 2x click))
        ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect      'To let it close
        ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide s.Slideindex  'make current slide active
     End If
Next s

 End Sub
```

A macro that opens the workbooks to refresh the charts and automatically closes them would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933346/how-to-refresh-data-via-vba-in-power-point)

Comment: Thank you James. I tried the chosen answer for that thread and it leaves 50 open workbooks on my desktop. I tried the last answer as well, but I get an error at this part "ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide s.Slideindex"

It would be great if a code could be written that refreshes and closes all the embedded workbooks.

Comment: Both the open workbooks and the error message are easily fixed. Please revise your question, adding what you're trying to use and we'll help.